# .htaccess rewrite to add .php to no extension requests, BUT to not accept .php requests by users

Tags: apache, request, url-rewriting, block

I want rewrite rules (mod_rewrite) that block users from accessing my pages directly, using .php extension at the end of URLs, but I want to keep my php files extension in my website folders. Another problem is that and I want the server to accept no extension URL requests, and take user to the respective .php page. I have the following rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The first rule is giving a 404 error, as I wanted. But the second rule only works when it's alone, with no other rules. With the above block, when I type a no extension URL I think the server is "redirecting" the request and adding a .php extension, but the first rule act like it was a user request and give me a 404 error, making the 2nd to not work like I want.

I think I need some rewrite condition to tell the server to apply the first rule only if the request comes from a website user, and ignore it if comes from the rewrite engine. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a htaccess guru yet, but I hope this helps:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^\/error\/.*$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: It didn't work. When I type some URL with .php at the end, it gives me a 404 error, just the way I want. But when I type some URL with no extension at the end, it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: The `^(.*)$` pattern may cause an infinite loop of matches. Try add the [L] to the second rewriterule. I update my answer with that. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: I tested and you are right. By adding two more rewriteconds it worked for me. The first one stops the loop and the second one prevents rewriting of the error pages' url. In my case they are in the "error" directory.